# State doesn't update when Input changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an `Input` component which has a function `UpdateState` to deal with the change.

```
  const UpdateState = e => {
setPayload([e.target.value]);
console.log("update state", payload);
};
```

The problem is that the state logged into the console is always the previous one, so I type a new value in the Input field the first time the state will still be empty, and if, for example, I add a space add the end, then the state will switch to the previously typed string:

[image]

How can I achieve a "live" state update?

This is my component using the function previously attached:

```
<FormControl fullWidth className={classes.textArea}>
      <Input
        onChange={e => {
          UpdateState(e);
        }}
        defaultValue={payload}
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.button}
        onClick={SubmitReview}
      >
        Submit{" "}
      </Button>
      {JSON.stringify(response.data.predictions)}
    </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` of `React.PureComponent` is asynchronous like `this.setState` of `React.Component`.

```
setPayload(e.target.value);
console.log("update state", payload); //Value here not yet updated
```

Try use `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // action on update of payload
    console.log(payload) // Value of payload will updated here
}, [payload]);

<Input
    onChange={e=> setPayload([e.target.value])}
    defaultValue={payload}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
remove the [] array  try without the     `setPayload(e.target.value);`

 const UpdateState = e => {
    setPayload(e.target.value);
    console.log("update state", payload);
    };

    <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.textArea}>
          <Input
            onChange={e=>
              UpdateState;}
            defaultValue={payload}
          />
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={SubmitReview}
          >
            Submit{" "}
          </Button>
          {JSON.stringify(response.data.predictions)}
        </FormControl>
```

tell me if it works or not

Comment: Thank for your help, unluckily it still does behave the same.

Comment: push the project may help you